# html5 canvas resize with javascript (not achieving desired result)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas

i was testing some code with javascript, about resizing the html5 canvas. i've asked similar question before, when i was testing the same thing with jquery. and i've got the desired solution that time, reference (eg_1). in this (eg_1), the result was, canvas element was resizing in every frame because of `requestAnimationFrame($.fn.animate);` is taking place in a recursive form.the visual result for that is [image] here the width attribute updates when i resize the console window. and if i close the console the canvas resizes automatically, i don't need to reload the window, to update the attribute values. means canvas is full screen, all time. but i am having problem with the same thing, in javascript. if i close the console, the width of the console cuts (or resizes) the canvas with a white space. here is the visual result [image] the white space is my problem. i've to reload the window, to make the canvas full screen again. in short i'm not having the same effect as (eg_1). here i tried so far, reference (eg_2).

(eg_1)

html : `<canvas></canvas>`

css :

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

canvas {
  background-color: turquoise;
}
```

jquery :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var view = $(window),
    canvas = $("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas[0].getContext("2d"),
    width = view.width(),
    height = view.height();

  $.fn.windowResize = function() {
    var width = view.width();
    height = view.height();

    canvas.attr("width", width);
    canvas.attr("height", height);
  };

  view.on("resize", $.fn.windowResize);

  canvas.attr("width", width);
  canvas.attr("height", height);

  $.fn.animate = function() {
    requestAnimationFrame($.fn.animate);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    // start here
  };

  $.fn.animate();
});
```

(eg_2)

```
var canvas = document.querySelectorAll("canvas")[0];
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;

function resize() {
  setInterval(resize, 5);
  clearInterval(resize);
  canvas.width = windowWidth;
  canvas.height = windowHeight;
}

resize();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer:

**Your initial issue:**

You need to get the updated values of `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight`.

To do this you can turn the variables into `functions` that request the **current** values.

---

### Example:

```js
var canvas = document.querySelectorAll("canvas")[0];
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var windowWidth = () => window.innerWidth;
var windowHeight = () => window.innerHeight;

function resize() {
  setInterval(resize, 5);
  clearInterval(resize);
  canvas.width = windowWidth();
  canvas.height = windowHeight();
}
resize();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

canvas {
  background-color: turquoise;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

---

### Other issues:

Your use of Timers is incorrect. `clearInterval(resize)` isn't going to clear anything, because `resize` is not a timer itself.

Secondly you shouldn't be using any timers when rendering to Canvas. It can often lead to things like the above( multiple timers ) or issues with constant, unnecessary, re-processing.

Instead of resizing perpetually you may want to just do so when the `resize` event is dispatched. Even if you were using `requestAnimationFrame` - which would effectively stop the render if anything else takes precedence or if you switch tabs, it's an unnecessary process in that you're constantly re-rendering the same thing without cause. Canvas Apps tend to get big real quick when you add in multiple rendering functions, so you'll want to mitigate unnecessary steps.

You can do this by attaching to appropriate events and creating `requestAnimationFrame` helpers like in the following example:

```js
var canvas = document.querySelectorAll("canvas")[0];
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var windowWidth = () => window.innerWidth;
var windowHeight = () => window.innerHeight;

var request = fn => requestAnimationFrame(fn),
requestHandler = fn => () => request(fn); 

function resize() {
  canvas.width = windowWidth();
  canvas.height = windowHeight();
}

request(resize);

window.addEventListener("resize", requestHandler(resize) );
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

canvas {
  background-color: turquoise;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```